# Is there workflow in git to share same file in multiple branch?

Tags: git

I have a project targeted to multiple platform. I have to change UI codes for different platform while keeping core classes same. To achieve this, I thought to make git branches for different platform.

Given the above scenario my requirement is, if I make changes in core classes it should be reflected in all git branches.

How to achieve this?

Or is there any other workflow to achieve the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Via `git rebase`

You may handle your specific platform via `git rebase` instead of `git merge`. In this case you will be able to change core branch and than rebase other branches on it keeping platform specific modifications applied over core.

#### Example workflow.

Make platform branches

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b platform1

git checkout master
git checkout -b platform2
```

Make core modifications

```
git checkout master
# make modification
git commit
```

Make platform modifications

```
git checkout platform2
# make modification
git commit
```

Import core changes in platforms

```
git checkout platform1
git rebase master

git checkout platform2
git rebase master
```

### Via `git merge`

It is also possible to use `git merge` with `strategy` option as said in [git merge manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html).

```
git checkout platform2
git merge -s recursive -X ours master
```

This will always choose platform specific changes in case of conflicts.

Comment: but isn't it possible to use `git merge` to achieve the same result?

Comment: @Alexis yes. it is possible. I've updated my answer to include the explanation.

Comment: shouldn't it be ``git merge -s recursive -X ours master``

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing in git.

If you are really after git solution, I suggest creating a "common" branch and have all your branches merge from that.

Always commit changes to common code to the "common" branch and merge that to platform branches, so you will prevent conflicts and merging things you do no want (or you can cherry-pick.)

Also I think you could make the commons file read-only on platform branches to prevent modifying it without being slapped.

CONS: Tedious, but should work.

Alternatively, use different subdirectories for each platform and let your build system pull in the right files for each build.

CONS: You won't get merges as with git branches.

Comment: There is everything inside git. You just need to know how to get it from git.

Comment: I do not see much difference between proposed merge and rebase solution except rebase will not work well with upstream (`git push`) and will screw up history.

Comment: Martian it's up to repository maintainer to decide what solution to use. "merge" solution will result in unpleasant history look that will a bit harder to understand. "rebase" solution will result in over writing history, you are right, but it represents exactly the platform specific branch mean. All platform specific changes will be applied over core branch as patches.

Comment: Yes, maintainer decides. But needs to know about drawbacks and rebasing published repo is considered a bad practice likely in every upstream project.

Comment: I think it is ok for platform specific branches in some cases. But you are right sometimes. It will be better to setup more complicated branches structure to avoid such conflicts. It might be core branch, platform patches (development) branches and additionally platform release branches. It depends on exact team workflow I think.